# What is the difference between 呀 and 啊?

Tags: meaning, difference, word

呀 and 啊 both seem to be used in the end of sentences for exclamation, and the only difference that I can think of is that the pronunciation in Putonghua (Mandarin) is different. In Cantonese, even the pronunciation is the same. Do 呀 and 啊 mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably or are their meaning different?

Comment: see grammars or dictionaries, e.g.＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂：呀［助］（aux。）used in place of 啊 when the preceding character ends in the sound a,o,e,i,or v (u umlaut) 是＂啊＂受前一字韵母a,o,e,i，v 的影响而发生的音变。

Comment: Reading all the questions here makes me doubt whether I am really a Chinese. I have never thought about this before. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ABC**'s entry for 呀 says:

> 呀
>
> ya5
>
> (replacing **a** (啊) when preceding word ends in **a**, **e**, **i**, **o**, or **(y)u**)
>
> 快来呀!
> Kuài lái ya!
> Come quickly!

**呀 is a replacement for 啊 when it comes after a vowel**.

This is also corroborated by《规范》's entry:

> 助 “啊(a)”受前一个音节末尾音素ɑ､e､o､i､ü的影响产生音变而采用的不同写法
>
> 说话(huà)呀 | 车(chē)呀 | 你说(shuō)呀 | 起来(lái)呀 | 快去(qù)呀。

Answer (score 2):

It's a hard question.

They are interchangeable most of time in this usage without affecting meaning. I can't think of an example in which you can only use one over the other.

To me, 呀 sounds more folksy, while 啊 sounds a bit more formal.

Comment: 我这儿经常听到‘啊懂啊？’，从来没听到‘呀懂呀？’

Answer (score 1):

The simplistic way to remember it is: they are various forms of 啊 depending on (the shape of the mouth in) the ending sound of the previous syllable.  There're also 哪 which is 啊 preceded by a final n-sound (人哪 Oh people!); 哇 (好哇；不够哇);啦 (preceded by 儿 sound in Northern-speak)；etc.

However, there is still a difference between them in some cases (need more context), sometimes conveying surprise, disbelief, amazement, etc.